# Error deploying VS 2015 application on server

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, office-interop

I am using **VS 2015** to create a console application that has a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. When I deploy it on a server (Windows Server 2012) I get the following error:

```
   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0004567-3456-
   0000-C002-000434000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154
```

I read some old postings that suggest I must have Office 2010 installed on the server. However, this is not possible. Is there any way to embed Excel assemblies in my application? 
Or is there any different approach to resolve this issue? What I need to do is just extract an Excel file sheet names as a list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that you need to have the host application installed on the target machine. When and where do you run the console application on the server?

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Or use any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for this detailed instructions.